# How do I set the provider for a TPushEvent?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a TPushEvent and TKinveyProvider declared on my firemonkey form

I'm trying to manually set the value of the Provider in code. I realize that by default when you drop those controls on a form the the PushEvent's Provider property is automatically set to the TKinveyProvider. However, I'm working around an apparent bug and I'd like set it later.

Am I setting the provider property correctly in this snippet?

```
//In my form class
//...
myPushEvents: TPushEvents;
myKinveyProvider: TKinveyProvider;

//later on in one of my procedures/methods
//...
myPushEvents.Provider := myKinveyProvider;
```

When I look a the value else later on after it should have been set, it still appears to be `nil`.

`Provider` appears to be defined as a `IBackendProvider` which is an interface and I'm not sure if I have to assign it its provider differently than I would with a simple data type like an Integer or a String.

Comment: You can assign a class that implements and interface to that interface directly. Just don't destroy the class manually, because the reference counting will do that for you.

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: @Johan More importantly can you give me an example? Are you thinking something like myPushEvents.Provider := TKinveyProvider.Create(nil);?

Comment: That indeed will let you assign a reference to a `TKinveyProvider` to `myPushEvents.Provider`. The negative being, that if you later want to change to properties of the `TKinveyProvider` you have to then cast `myPushEvents.Provider` as a `TKinveyProvider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the right way to do it.

```
myPushEvents.Provider := myKinveyProvider
```

In this cases `myPushEvents.Provider` is being assigned a reference to `myKinveyProvider`. You don't have to do any special casting because  `myPushEvents.Provider` expects something that conforms to the `IBackendProvider` interfcase, and `myKinveyProvider` (a `TKinveyProvider`) does.

Note: In my specific case, thanks to `myPushEvents.Provider` being set as the result of a timer finishing, it was indeed still `nil`.

Adding an

```
if (myPushEvents.Provider <> nil) then
begin
  // ... use myPushEvents.Provider
end;
```

protected the usage of it until the value had been set properly after the timer ran.